# how to keep session and CSRF token in locust test

Tags: debugging, csrf, locust

I wan't to test my django web app with locust.io. In a form I have a problem with CSRF token. I do the following:

```
class WebsiteTasks(TaskSet):
    def on_start(self):
        print("On start")

    @task
    def post_answer(self):
        self.client.get("/polls/2/vote")
        self.client.post("/polls/2/vote/", {"choice": "8"})
```

Why do I get a `403` error? That the post is forbidden, the locust documentation says that the client objects keeps the session alive..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

change your code as:

```
@task
def post_answer(self):
    response = self.client.get("/polls/2/vote")
    csrftoken = response.cookies['csrftoken']

    self.client.post("/polls/2/vote/", 
                     {"choice": "8"}, 
                     headers={"X-CSRFToken": csrftoken})
```

Comment: This will failed on flask-wtf I think. Should I parse the "session=...." to get csrftoken in flask?

Comment: you also need to send the token in cookies

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this problem running a Locust test against Django 1.8.5 and it required adding the csrf token to the cookies, headers, and form POST data as well like below in order to not get caught up with a 403.  Something like:

```
@task
def post_answer(self):
    response = self.client.get("/polls/2/vote")
    csrftoken = response.cookies['csrftoken']

    self.client.post("/polls/2/vote/", {"choice": "8",
                     "csrfmiddlewaretoken": csrftoken}, 
                     headers={"X-CSRFToken": csrftoken},
                     cookies={"csrftoken": csrftoken})
```